# HttpClient.GetAsync(requestUri) not fetching the full content from url

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, uwp, httpclient

After upgrading the version of `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` package in my UWP app from 5.0.0 to 6.2.9, `HttpClient.GetAsync(requestUri)` is not downloading the entire content from url.

I am using `HttpClient.GetAsync()` to get contents of the page and then extract some info from it. [eg link](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%20definition:Minister&setmkt=en-us&setlang=en-us).
With 5.0.0 it was working as expected and the entire [page content](https://jsfiddle.net/tper4c5y/) was downloaded. But after upgrading to 6.2.9, looks like only the schema is getting [downloaded and not the content](https://jsfiddle.net/mrhfc91b/).

One thing I noticed is that the location of System.Net.Http.dll has changed between the versions:

- 5.0.0: C:\Users\xx.nuget\packages\system.net.http\4.0.0\ref\netcore50\System.Net.Http.dll
- 6.2.9: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\system.net.http\4.1.0\ref\netcore50\System.Net.Http.dll

This is the code I  am using:

```
public static async void GetDataAsync(string url, Action<string> OnSuccess, Action<string> OnFailure)
{
    HttpClient _floatHttpClient = new HttpClient();
    string responseText = null;
    try
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await _floatHttpClient.GetAsync(url);

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        responseText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        OnSuccess(responseText);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        OnFailure(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

How to download the full content from url with 6.2.9 package?

This is the caller method.

```
private void def_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DictDialog dictDialog = new DictDialog(Contentgrid.ActualWidth, Contentgrid.ActualHeight);
    dictDialog.ShowAsync();

    string url = "https://www.bing.com/search?q=+definition:" + dictWord + "&setmkt=en-us&setlang=en-us";

    WebRequest.GetDataAsync(url, (string html) =>
    {
        if (html != null)
        {
            bool defFound = false;
            string def = readerVM.GetDefinitionBing(html, out defFound);

            if (defFound == true)
            {
                dictDialog.LoadHtml(def);
            }
            else
            {
                dictDialog.ShowNoDefMsg();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            dictDialog.LoadFailed();
        }
    },
    (string error) =>
    {
        dictDialog.LoadFailed();
    });
}
```

Comment: `async void` is only acceptable for writing event handlers. that may not be your issue, but it would be useful to see the call site.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "useful to see the call site", can you plz elaborate a little?

Comment: Yes, it means that I want to see where you call the method

Comment: Hello, I am trying to upgrade the `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` nuget package to 6.2.9 and try to download a bing search results page that performs well. I observed the download results you gave. It can be seen that the poorly performing page is indeed a complete HTML document, which means that the page is indeed downloaded. You can try to update the link for the search page, it may be out of date

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT, I understand that if you go to Bing home page and search for something, then use that browser URL with 6.2.9 package, GetAsync() gives similar result as the browser. 
My question is, when you open this url in browser "https://www.bing.com/search?q=+definition:Minister&setmkt=en-us&setlang=en-us", and also do a GetAsync() with 5.0.0 and 6.2.9, the result of 5.0.0 and browser are similar but with 6.2.9 package the result is different. This is what I am concerned about, there is some change under the hood which is causing this and I want to understand that.

Comment: @AluanHaddad, I have updated the question with the caller method.

Comment: @ac-lap Have you tried anything other website than bing? After testing, I did not see any significant differences. If you think that the upgrade has a big impact on the page difference, please consider the reason of the HTTP request header, or install the nuget package of the corresponding version of `System.Net.Http`.